# How do I change the branch I am currently developing for in Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am using Visual Studio 2013 on a project with Team Foundation Server. I created a new branch, but when I click "Get Latest Version", I get the latest version from the old branch, not the new branch, and when I commit changes, the changes are made to the old branch. How can I change the current branch in Visual Studio 2013 so I can develop on the new branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using TFVC. Branches in TFVC are represented in different folders in the source control explorer and in your file system.

If you want to make changes on a branch, open the solution file from the appropriate branch. If it's not in your file system, map a workspace to the appropriate branch.